# download csv file from external oneDrive gives only text/html file using download.files() in r

Tags: r, download

My friend has a file in his oneDrive folder `mtcars.csv`.  I used the following code to download the csv file to my local folder called 'temp'.

```
download.file('oneDrive_link_to_csv',  destfile =  "./temp/mtcars.csv")
```

What I got is `mtcars.csv` in my temp folder. However, I found I cannot read the file with `read.csv`.  I opened the file with excel and found it is something like a text/html type of format. Not like rows and columns.

Does anyone know what happened? how I can download the file that is readable by `read.csv`?  The csv file in the oneDrive folder is OK. I double checked.

Comment: The link you were given was likely not a link to the actual file contents, but a link to a web page that shows the file contents. Or the link requires you to log in to get the contents and `download.file` cannot log in for you. Really hard to say what's going on with any specifics to test with. What exactly is in the file that was downloaded?

Comment: Does it contain the data (along with the text/html formatting)?  Or is the data missing from the file?

Comment: It contains data with text/html formatting

Answer (score 0):

Per https://medium.com/@benjaminobi/download-a-file-from-the-internet-using-the-r-functions-download-file-and-read-csv-e7bd415648e4, you may need to use the URL for the raw version (csv) of the file not the html version.

Comment: Thanks for the article.  The problem is how I can find the link to the raw file.  In windows, I right click the file, then click on share, and then click copy link. That's the link I get. Unaware any other link to use.  Can someone try to put `mtcars.csv` in oneDrive and give it a try?  And what if I want to downlaod all the files in a oneDrive folder?  @TJ87 @MrFlick @Monk